# Display local timezone name with moment.js

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I am using **moment.js** and would like to show the user's [local timezone name](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/) like CET or PST using

```
var timezone_local = moment.tz().zoneName(); 
document.getElementById('timezone_local').innerHTML = timezone_local;
```

Those lines do not work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you have a look at http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/ ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have edited the question. But that doesn't work. I just need to display the timezone. No date conversion, no other specials :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to the official moment document, you can use moment-timezone

```
moment.tz.guess();
```

For further formatting, refer to [this](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/).

Edited :

```
var zone_name =  moment.tz.guess();
var timezone = moment.tz(zone_name).zoneAbbr() 
console.log(timezone);
```

Refer to [this working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajays871/2mpkefqn/4).

Comment: I already had that, but couldn't get it run. Can maybe someone fiddle this for me? Thanks so much!

Comment: sure. do have cdn link for momentjs

Comment: Looks nice, but can't get it to work. Nothing shows up :(

Comment: i have edited the answer with working fiddle. Please refer it and you also need to add two momentjs libraries that i have attached to fiddle from cdn

Comment: Oh my god! I really forgot to include **moment-timezone-with-data.js**. Please don't tell anyone! Sorry, sorry, sorry! Works now. But I don't get the **.zoneAbbr();** to show up.

Comment: glad you figured out. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132644/discussion-between-user3775217-and-vloryan).

Comment: But how do I get the timezone abbreviation, given the timezone offset. Eg: +5:30 it should give me IST

Comment: can you guys answer this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62798753/is-zone-abbreviation-using-moment-zone-library-a-dynamic

Answer (score 1):

I'm just doing this. The `z` in the format adds the proper abbreviation for the timezone.

```
 moment().tz('America/New_York').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a z');
```

Answer (score 1):

`.format("z")` with a lowercase `z` prints out just the timezone abbreviation.

Here are a few examples:

```
let currentTime = moment().tz(moment.tz.guess());
console.log(currentTime.format("z")); // PST

let parisTime = moment().tz("Europe/Paris");
console.log(parisTime.format("z")); // CET

let indiaTime = moment().tz("Asia/Kolkata");
console.log(indiaTime.format("z")); // IST

let newYorkTime = moment().tz("America/New_York");
console.log(newYorkTime.format("z")); // EST

let newYorkTimeDuringDST = moment("2020-08-01").tz("America/New_York");
console.log(newYorkTimeDuringDST.format("z")); // EDT
```

Comment: This is deprecated as of 1.6.0 https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeZone = moment.tz.guess();
const zoneName = moment.tz(timeZone).zoneName();
return moment().tz("America/New_York").zoneName();
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Include moment.js and moment-timezone-with-data.js javascript library.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Then use the below code to get the browser timezone name.

```
<script>
var timezone = moment.tz.guess();
console.log(timezone);
</script>
```

See the timezone name in the browser console.