# Is Zone abbreviation using moment-zone library a dynamic

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am using moment timezone library to show the zone abbreviation after the timestamp.
I am using the following snippet to show the zone abbreviation of New York, USA

```
 var timeZone = moment.tz.guess();
    const zoneName = moment.tz(timeZone).zoneName();
    return moment().tz("America/New_York").zoneName();
```

This returns me the Zone abbreviation **EDT**.
My question is: when winter will come will it automatically return **EST**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will.

```
var jun = moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
var dec = moment("2014-12-01T12:00:00Z");

jun.tz('America/New_York').format('ha z');     // 8am EDT
dec.tz('America/New_York').format('ha z');     // 7am EST
```

[Source](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)